# Restricting create button on a related list for few profile users on a page layout

Tags: lightning, page-layout, sharing, record-type, app-builder

I have a page layout with multiple related lists, my requirement is on this particular layout I want to disable create button on one of the related object for a some profile users  (we have a profile with 10 users , out of all only 2 can create, rest need read only access)

I tried multiple approaches but none of them work

1. for profile users I created 2 permission sets -one with CRED and another with read only access
   in this approach they can view button but fields are disappeared
2. as we know we cant create layouts for permission sets yet and multiple layouts for profile
3. validation rule with custom permission which allows some users to create (but this works across the org ,but i want this feature in page layout level.
   Is it possible?

None of the above approches worked, am i missing something?
im starting to think my requirement is not possible.
feel free to share your solutions

Comment: Approach 1 sounds like it should work. Did you also give edit/read access on the specific fields for the object in the permission set?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove Create access from the Profile, then generate one permission set:

```
 CreateOnXXXX
```

that grants Create access on the object. Assign that Permission Set to the two (2) users.

Permission Sets are additive in permissions to the underlying profile so you'll want to start with a profile that grants no Create access, then add in permissions

See also [Muting Permissions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.perm_set_groups_create_mute.htm&type=5) which provides a way to remove permissions from users - there are limitations